# setflash using errorsummary in yii

Tags: yii

how would i go about this? I am looking to have the errorsummary in the flash messages.

in controller:

```
Yii::app()->user->setFlash('error', Controller::errorSummary($model));
```

in view:

```
<?php echo Yii::app()->user->getFlash('error'); ?>
```

it says there is no errorsummary in controller. So i am confused where am i suppose to put this. I have this all in a module (profile controller and view). Am i suppose to have an errorsummary in the profilecontroller,which i dont understand why there should be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`errorSummary` is a method of `CActiveForm`

```
<?php $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm'); ?>
<?php echo $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'firstName'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'firstName'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'firstName'); ?>
</div>
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

Comment: That i get. But it still answers how would i put the errorsummary in setflash.

Comment: `CHtml::errorSummary($model)` instead of `Controller::errorSummary($model)`